# How to align two sets of icons on the same row

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, dreamweaver

I Have two sets of icons. 4 icons that i want on the left and 4 icons i want on the right on the same line at the bottom of the page just above the footer. my code is as follows

any help is much appreciated.

```
<div class="all">
      <div class="symbols">
        <i class="fab fa-cc-visa"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-cc-paypal"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-cc-mastercard"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-cc-amex"></i>
        </div>
        
          <div class="social">
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
<i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
<i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
        </div>
        </div>
CSS

div .symbols {
    
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    color:red;
}
div .social {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 25px;
    color:red;
    
}

all {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add in the icon js file.  also, use flex box

```css
.all {
   
    display:flex;    
    justify-content:space-between;
    color:red;
    
}
```

```html
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<div class="all">
      <div class="symbols">
        <div class="fab fa-cc-visa"></div>
        <div class="fab fa-cc-paypal"></div>
        <div class="fab fa-cc-mastercard"></div>
        <div class="fab fa-cc-amex"></div>
      </div>        
      <div class="socials">
        <div class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></div>
        <div class="fab fa-twitter-square"></div>
        <div class="fab fa-instagram"></div>
        <div class="fab fa-facebook-square"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div .symbols {
    display:inile-block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    color:red;
}
div .social {
    display:inile-block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .row{
   font-size:25px;
   color:red;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" style="display:inline-block;float:left" >
      <i class="fab fa-cc-visa"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-cc-paypal"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-cc-mastercard"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-cc-amex"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="display:inline-block;float:right">
      <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
<i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
<i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
    </div>
 
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all for your input.

I changed my code for social and symbols within the css to
float:left instead of text-align:left.

once i did this the icons lined up and removed excess space aswell. problem solved

Thanks

Comment: use flexbox.  it's simpler